# How to Identify simple tense or passive voice in sentence

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

Please help me with below example and explain how to indentify quickly if simple tense past/present and passive voice.

> 1. My clothes were scattered in my bedroom.

It means when I entered in my bedroom my clothes were in scattered state.
Or
It means my clothes were scattered by someone

> 2. Three people were killed.

It means three people were killed (maybe in an earthquake or a flood).
Or
It means three people were killed by killer.

My question is whether the meaning of my sentences is that cloths were scattered by someone or just in the state of scatteredness when I entered the room. Clothes were maybe scattered by a cyclone or something.

Answer (score 2):

In both these cases, the passive form just describes the state of their objects, with no reference to the doer.

For instance, **The vase was shattered** just describes the state of the vase, which could have been shot with a gun, thrown against a wall, or dropped on the floor. The passive here just expresses it's state, like any other adjective would, at any point after it broke.

The same with "killed." However, if the victim was **murdered** then the doer would have to be a human perpetrator, since this is a valency requirement for that specific verb: humans murder humans.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is whether the meaning of my sentences is that cloths were shattered by someone or just in the state of shattered when I entered in room. Cloths were may be shattered by cyclone or something.

Comment: It just refers to the state of the clothes, so in these case, when you walked into the room, there were clothes scattered all over the place.